# Can someone please help me in solving why my codepen script won't run in a text-editor?

Tags: javascript

http://codepen.io/Zulu/pen/Kztov here's the source code: why is this script running in codepen fine but not in the browsers?

Heya, i've been prototyping in codepen.io but now it's time to move it into a text-editor,
however for some reason the script doesn't run from the text editor in a browser, is codepen letting me get away with syntax errors? cause it runs fine in codepen

any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
     <!doctype html>

<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css" />


    <script> 
    alert("ahhhhg");


    var c = document.getElementById("playground");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 

 //global scope
  var i=0; 

var c1 = []; //c is short for collect
var c2 = [];
var c3 = [];
var c4 = [];
var c5 = [];
var c6 = [];

var initiate = function(){ //the button that triggers the program
  var timer = setInterval(function(){clock()},90); //copy this block for ref.


 function clock(){



  i+=1; 

   var a = Math.round(Math.random()*200); 
   var b = Math.round(Math.random()*250); 
   var c = Math.round(Math.random()*200); 
   var d = Math.round(Math.random()*250); 
   var e = Math.round(Math.random()*200); 
   var f = Math.round(Math.random()*250); 
   c1.push(a); 
   c2.push(b);
   c3.push(c);
   c4.push(d);
   c5.push(e);
   c6.push(f);

 // document.write(i);
   ctx.beginPath(); 
   ctx.moveTo(c3[i-2], c4[i-2]);
   ctx.bezierCurveTo(c1[i-2],c2[i-2],c5[i-2],c6[i-2],c3[i-1], c4[i-1]);
  // ctx.lineTo(c3[i-1], c4[i-1]); 

   if(a<200){
      ctx.strokeStyle="#FF33CC";   
   }
   else if(a<400){

     ctx.strokeStyle="#FF33aa";
   }
   else{
      ctx.strokeStyle="#FF3388";

   }



   ctx.stroke(); 

   document.getElementById("text-box").innerHTML=i+"<p>Thoughts.</p>"; 
  if(i===20){
    //alert("15 reached");
    clearInterval(timer);//to clearInterval must be using a global scoped variable.
    return; 
  }

 }; //end of clock











//setInterval(clock,150);
  var targetFace = document.getElementById("face");
  var face = targetFace.getContext("2d");


  var faceTimer = setInterval(function(){faceAnim()},80); //copy this block for ref.

  function faceAnim(){

     face.beginPath(); 

  face.strokeStyle="#FF33CC";

  face.moveTo(100,104); //eye line
  face.bezierCurveTo(150,125,250,125,300,104);



  face.moveTo(200,1); //centre line
  face.lineTo(200,400);

  face.moveTo(125,111);//left eye lid
  face.bezierCurveTo(160,135,170,130,185,120);



  face.moveTo(150,116);//left eye 
  face.bezierCurveTo(155,125,165,125,170,118);

    face.moveTo(275,111);//right eye lid
face.bezierCurveTo(240,135,230,130,215,120);



  face.moveTo(250,116);//right eye 
  face.bezierCurveTo(245,125,235,125,230,118);

  face.moveTo(195, 118); //left nose
  face.lineTo(190, 160);
  face.lineTo(200,170);

  face.moveTo(190,160); //left nostroll
  face.lineTo(180,160);
  face.lineTo(191,154);

   face.moveTo(180,160); //left lower nostrol
  face.lineTo(200,170);

   face.moveTo(205, 118); //right nose
  face.lineTo(210, 160);
  face.lineTo(200,170);

  face.moveTo(210,160); //right nostroll
  face.lineTo(220,160);
  face.lineTo(209,154);

  face.moveTo(220,160); //right lower nostrol
  face.lineTo(200,170);



  face.moveTo(200,140); //outer triad
  face.lineTo(170, 100);
   face.lineTo(230, 100);
   face.lineTo(200, 140);

   face.moveTo(200,145); //outer triad drop shadow
  face.lineTo(170, 100);
   face.lineTo(230, 100);
   face.lineTo(200, 145);

    face.moveTo(200,130); //inner triad
  face.lineTo(180, 105);
   face.lineTo(220, 105);
   face.lineTo(200, 130);

  //face.lineWidth =0.6; 

        face.moveTo(280,111);//outer right eye lid
face.bezierCurveTo(240,140,230,135,210,120);

     face.moveTo(120,111);//outer left eye lid 
  face.bezierCurveTo(160,140,170,135,190,120);








    face.moveTo(162,174); //upper mouth line
  face.bezierCurveTo(170,180,230,180,238,174);

   face.moveTo(165,175); //mouth line bottom
  face.bezierCurveTo(190,Math.floor(Math.random()*25+180),210,Math.floor(Math.random()*25+180),235,175);


    face.moveTo(232,204); //head shape
    face.lineTo(340, 20);

        face.moveTo(168,204); //head shape
    face.lineTo(60, 20);

  face.stroke(); //exicute all co-ords.


  }; //end of face anim








    var clearFace = function(){

   document.getElementById('face').getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, 700, 750);

};

setInterval(clearFace,90); 





}; //end of parent function







    </script>

  </head>


  <body>
    <canvas id="playground" width="200px" height="250px">
    </canvas>

     <h2> <em>Fantastical place<br/>prototype</em> </h2>

 <div id="button-box">   
    <button id="activate" onClick="initiate()" width="50px" height="50px" title="Activate">  </button> 
 </div>  

    <div id="text-box"> 
    </div>

    <canvas id="face" width="400px" height="200px">
    </canvas>




  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console?

Comment: TypeError: c is null
 

var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

Comment: Can you post the full code of the page you're getting the error in in your question?

Comment: woaw, is there an easier way of formatting code than indenting by 4 spaces?

Comment: posted the source code ! i'm quite new to stackoverflow sorry, getting the hang of it's formmating tools.

Comment: I don't know why, but I find that javascript works when in the body rather than the head. You could try putting it in the body.

Comment: oki doki, i'll give it ago niceone!

Comment: Looks like `document.getElementById("playground")` is returning null. Check that the element does in fact exist. And check for timing issues (like if it doesn't exist until after that line is called.

Comment: rofl good find! beats me.. i'm using like a js hack where i create a random canvas image and wipe it immediately, to get a stop frame animation effect. well niceone anyway!

Comment: oki forgiven, shall do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it works in codepen and not your page is because codepen places the code at the end of the document, before the closing body element. You're placing the code in the head of the document, and the browser is running the code (or trying to run it) before the elements exist on the page.

Either move your code to the end of the document, before the closing body tag, or wrap it in a window onload event wrapper (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload).